# Making a localhost apache webserver go live

Tags: apache, url, webserver, live

I have looked all over the internet and I can't a reasonable way to make my web-server running on apache go live with an unique ip and everything. How would i got about making it live and viewable for other people?

Answer (score 1):

Normally you would not do this.  You'd buy a hosting account from some provider like GoDaddy, BlueHost, etc. and put your software there, and make it visible that way.  Making your localhost server viewable would involve buying a static IP, which is not cost effective for most people.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it depends on what you mean by "go live" if you need it to host a specific domain name then yes - get a shared hosting account somewhere ~ if you just need access to it and it does not matter what the domain name is, you can use something like DynDNS: http://www.dyndns.com/services/dns/dyndns/

-sean